# Speeding up the trainning - RNN with LSTM in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, dataloader

I am trying to train a LSTM for energy demand forecast but it takes too long. I do not understand why because the model looks “simple” and there is no much data. Might it be because I am not using the DataLoader? How could I use it with RNN since I have a sequence?

Complete code is in Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/130rG8_j1Lf8RQoVRrfXCeo5h_CcC5NU6?usp=sharing

The interesting part to be improved may be this:

```
for seq, y_train in train_data:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    model.hidden = (torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size),
                    torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size))
    y_pred = model(seq)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Thanks in advance to anyone helping me.

Comment: It is slow maybe because you are not training on GPU.

Comment: Thanks @GirishDattatrayHegde, that is true but the dataset is small enough and other models run faster being more complex.

Comment: What do you mean by "more complex" models? I mean, which models are faster than RNNs in your end? Cause, RNNs if are not the most complicated neural models, but definitely are among such "complex" models due to their recurrent nature. @jccarrasco

Comment: What do you mean by too long? What is the time for one epoch?

Comment: I think you should use other optimizer like Adam or RMSprop which are much more rapid than SGD optimizer.

Comment: Thanks @inverted_index, the problem was located in the batch loading. I was passing just 1 batch per training.I will write the solution.

Comment: Thanks @DimitriK.Sifoua. The problem was in the dataloader. I will answer the question.

Comment: Please@DimitriK.Sifoua vote the solution up if you found it useful.

Comment: Please@GirishDattatrayHegde vote the solution up if you found it useful.

Comment: Please@inverted_index vote the solution up if you found it useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should you want to speed up the process of training, more data must be provided to the model per training. In my case I was providing just 1 batch. The best way to simply solve this is using the DataLoader.

Complete Colab with the solution can be found in this link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QgtshCFETZ9oTvIYWy1Bdre-614kbwRX?usp=sharing

```
# This is to create the Dataset
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class DemandDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X_train, y_train):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y_train)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        data = self.X_train[idx]
        labels = self.y_train[idx]
        return data, labels

#This is to convert from typical RNN sequences
sq_0 =[]
y_0 =[]
for seq, y_train in train_data:
  sq_0.append(seq)
  y_0.append(y_train)

dataset=DemandDataset(sq_0,y_0)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=20)

epochs = 30
t = 50

for i in range(epochs):
    print("New epoch")    
  
    for data,label in dataloader:
         
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        model.hidden = (torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size),
                        torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size))
        
        y_pred = model(seq)
        
        loss = criterion(y_pred, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
   
    print(f'Epoch: {i+1:2} Loss: {loss.item():10.8f}')
    
   
    preds = train_set[-window_size:].tolist()

    for f in range(t):  
        seq = torch.FloatTensor(preds[-window_size:])
        with torch.no_grad():
            model.hidden = (torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size),
                            torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size))
            preds.append(model(seq).item())
            
    loss = criterion(torch.tensor(preds[-window_size:]),y[-t:])
```